# How to compile libpng16 for SteamOS using CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libpng, steamos

For Ubuntu, I successfully compiled my game using CMake. Now I would like to run it on SteamOS as well, as I am publishing on Steam (SteamOS + Linux).

I am using `libpng16`, but SteamOS 2 is based on Debian 8 Jessie, which uses `libpng12`. I believe that it does not support `libpng16` yet. And I don't believe the latest version of Ubuntu still includes `libpng12`.

How do I compile a single build for both platforms?

**Some sample code (if useful):**

```
...

find_package(PNG REQUIRED)

...

include_directories(
    ...
    ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

...

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ...
    ${PNG_LIBRARY}
)
```

Comment: The most direct way would be to install Debian 8 (e.g. on virtual machine) and build you game on it. Alternatively, you could install libpng12 on your machine and tell CMake to use it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your comment! I just have a question, if I build it using `libpng12`, wouldn't it require `libpng12.so` on the target machine? So in case I would run it on Ubuntu 20, it might not be there?

Comment: No, the project compiled against libpng12 won't work with libpng16. Note, that package [libpng16-16](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libpng16-16/filelist) provides `libpng16.so.16` file, so even component `.16` should match when use the library. If you want your project to work on OS with libpng12 and on OS with libpng16, then you need to build project **twice**: once for the first OS and once for the second.

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. Thank you for your comment, it answers my question

Comment: an other way, would be to integrate libpng12/16 directly in your build as a subproject (e.g. FetchContent + patch to cmake is it if needed)

Comment: @Mizux That sounds really good. I've just read some of its documentation. Would you give me an example on how to do something like that please?